# Hacer consulta where de un atributo de un modelo en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

me encuentro haciendo una consulta con laravel.

Deseo obtener los  **registros** que solamente que su **atributo agregado del modelo  "qualified" sea true**

En mi modelo UserMembreship agrego el atributo qualified

```
<?php
class UserMembreship extends Authenticatable
{
      protected $appends = [
        'qualified',
    ];

public function classified(): HasMany
{
      return $this->hasMany(Classified::class, 'id_user_sponsor','id');
}

    public function getQualifiedAttribute() : bool
    {
        $qualified = false;
        $left =  $this->classified()->where('status_position_left',1)->exists();
        $rigth = $this->classified()->where('status_position_right',1)->exists();
        if($left && $rigth){
          $qualified = true;
        }
        return $qualified; 
    }
}
```

Consutla para obtener los registros

```
 public function consulta()
{

    $users = UserMembreship::where('request', 2)->select('id', 'id_referrer_sponsor AS pid', 'name', 'last_name', 'expiration_date','created_at')->get();
    return $users;

}
```

Resultado de la consulta

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Si hago la misma consulta en tinker se puede apreciar cuales son campos de la tabla y atributos

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4465
 all: [
   App\Models\UserMembreship {#4454
     id: 1,
     pid: 0,
     name: "Administrator",
     last_name: "Promolider",
     expiration_date: "2031-09-15 23:16:02",
     created_at: "2020-09-15 23:16:02",
     +fullName: "Administrator Promolider",
     +LeftPoints: 0,
     +RightPoints: 0,
     +active: true,
     +Photo: "https://iconape.com/wp-content/png_logo_vector/user-tie.png",
     +qualified: true,
   },
   App\Models\UserMembreship {#4455
     id: 2,
     pid: 1,
     name: "Wiliam",
     last_name: "Ramirez",
     expiration_date: "2021-10-14 12:42:24",
     created_at: "2020-09-15 23:16:02",
     +fullName: "Wiliam Ramirez",
     +LeftPoints: 0,
     +RightPoints: 0,
     +active: true,
     +Photo: "https://iconape.com/wp-content/png_logo_vector/user-tie.png",
     +qualified: false,
   },
   App\Models\UserMembreship {#4458
     id: 3,
     pid: 1,
     name: "Jesus",
     last_name: "Paredes",
     expiration_date: "2021-10-08 22:14:39",
     created_at: "2020-09-15 23:16:02",
     +fullName: "Jesus Paredes",
     +LeftPoints: 0,
     +RightPoints: 0,
     +active: true,
     +Photo: "https://iconape.com/wp-content/png_logo_vector/user-tie.png",
     +qualified: false,
   },
 ],
```

}

Buenas estoy haciendo una consulta con laravel.
Quiero mostrar los registros con qualified true en este caso el primer objecto cumple la condición los demás no

Y como veo no se puede hacer un where de un atributo ,lo he intentando en php artisan tinker

```
>>App\Models\UserMembreship::where('qualified',true)->get();

# Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'qualified' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_membreships` where `qualified` = 1)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Tu método *accessor* no requiere de una propiedad a la cual le asignes un valor y posterior retornarla, así entonces puedes evaluar la condición y deolver `true` o `false` según sea el caso.

  ```
    public function getQualifiedAttribute(): bool
    {
        $left =  $this->classified()->where('status_position_left',1)->exists();
        $rigth = $this->classified()->where('status_position_right',1)->exists();

        if ($left && $rigth) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
  ```
- Posterior obtienes de manera regular tus registros por medio de tu query, solo que al final y dado que obtienes una colección entonces puedes filtrarlos indicando la clave (*que en este caso sería la propiedad recién agregada*):

  ```
  $users = UserMembreship::query()
                         ->where('request', 2)
                         ->select([
                                   'id', 
                                   'id_referrer_sponsor AS pid',
                                   'name', 
                                   'last_name', 
                                   'expiration_date',
                                   'created_at'
                                  ])->get()->filter(function($claveColeccion) {
                                      return $claveColeccion->qualified === true;
                                  });
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D